# Generic task wrapper

Tags: c++

Let's say this is how I dispatch a task to the gui thread:

```
void DispatchToGuiThread(std::function<void(void)> task);
```

I want a generic `GUIDispatchedTask` class that turns this:

```
// foo takes some arguments and must be run in the gui thread

auto guiDispatchedTask = [] (A a, B b, C c, D d) {
  DispatchToGuiThread(
    [a = a, b = b, c = c] {
      foo(a, b, c);
    }
  );
};
```

to this:

```
auto guiDispatchedTask = GUIDispatchedTask{ foo };
```

I don't want to repeat the arguments of `foo` like `GUIDispatchedTask<A, B, C>` because `foo` is likely going to be a lambda and repeating the arguments is tedious. I could not make that work.

Comment: Must the arguments be deduced right away? Maybe use a templated `operator()`?

Comment: not sure what you want. isn't directly `DispatchToGuiThread([=]{foo(a,b,c);})` simpler?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Great idea. It did work. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it with generic lambda.

```
template<typename F>
auto GUIDispatchedTask(F f){
    return [=](auto&&... args){
        DispatchToGuiThread([=]{f(args...);});
    };
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is cleaner. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Using an idea from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789646/generic-task-wrapper#comment123361157_69789646), here's what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

void DispatchToGuiThread(std::function<void(void)> task) {
  puts("in gui thread");
  task();
}

template <class Func>
struct GUIDispatchedTask
{
private:
  Func _func;

public:
  GUIDispatchedTask(Func func)
    : _func(std::move(func))
  {}

  template <class ...T>
  void operator()(T... args) {
    DispatchToGuiThread([this, ...args = args] {
        _func(args...);
    });
  }
};

void foo(int a, int b, int c) {
  printf("a = %d\nb = %d\nc = %d\n", a, b, c);
}

int main() {
  auto guiFoo = GUIDispatchedTask{foo};

  guiFoo(1, 2, 3);
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ardY9Y9vP)